# What's the name of this element?

Tags: android

I'm making an app and I want to implement an element but I don't know how is it called, it's the one that appears in the lists section at the top in the foursquare app I think it's an image slider but I really don't know could anybody tell me please? where can I check this in the future? i checked in the android developers page but I can't see a preview of the elements, I'm sorry if this seems dumb but I'm new to android, thank you for your time and your help

It is something like this but with some text below the image
[image]

Comment: check out this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/). i think you are looking for this!

Answer (score 0):

Try ViewFlipper

[ViewFlipper Spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)